# how to round an odd integer towards the nearest power of two

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, rounding

Add one to or subtract one from an odd integer such that the even result is closer to the nearest power of two.

```
if ( ??? ) x += 1; else x -= 1;// x > 2 and odd
```

For example, 25 through 47 round towards 32, adding one to 25 through 31 and subtracting one from 33 through 47.  23 rounds down towards 16 to 22 and 49 rounds up towards 64 to 50.

Is there a way to do this without finding the specific power of two that is being rounded towards.  I know how to use a logarithm or count bits to get the specific power of two.

My specific use case for this is in splitting odd sized inputs to karatsuba multiplication.

Comment: So nothing has to be done to even integers

Comment: For my use case, even integers do not change.

Comment: Check out my code, it contains the solution for the log indexing one, I'm going to make the first function a constexpr but you get the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second most significant bit is set then add, otherwise subtract.

if ( (x&(x>>1)) > (x>>2) ) x += 1; else x -= 1;

Comment: Ok I guess this is actually pretty clever ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I had a few false starts before I finally figured it out.

Comment: I think creating a vector<bool> at compile time might still technically be faster, just sayin

Comment: That being said you could use your trick to generate the vector

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a big deal to keep all of the powers of 2 for a 32 bit integer (only 32 entries) do a quick binary search for the location it's supposed to be in. Then you can easily figure out which number it's closer to by subtracting from the higher and lower numbers and getting the abs. Then you can easily decide which one to add to.

You may be able to avoid the search by taking the log base 2 of your number and using that to index into the array

**UPDATE:** reminder this code is not thoroughly tested.

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

    const std::array<unsigned int,32> powers = 
    {
        1,1<<1,1<<2,1<<3,1<<4,1<<5,1<<6,1<<7,1<<8,1<<9,1<<10,1<<11,1<<12,1<<13,1<<14,
            1<<15,1<<16,1<<17,1<18,1<<19,1<<20,1<<21,1<<22,1<<23,1<<24,1<<25,1<<26,1<<27,
            1<<28,1<<29,1<<30,1<<31 -1
    };
    std::array<unsigned int,32> powers_of_two() {
        std::array<unsigned int,32> powers_of_two{};
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 31; ++i) {
            powers_of_two[i] = 1 << i;
        }
        powers_of_two[31]=~0;
        return powers_of_two;
    }

    unsigned int round_to_closest(unsigned int number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) return number;
        unsigned int i = std::ceil(std::log2(number));
        //higher index
        return (powers[i]-number) < (number - powers[i-1]) ?
            ++number:--number;
    }

    int main() {
        std::cout << round_to_closest(27) << std::endl;
        std::cout << round_to_closest(23) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Since I can't represent 2 ^ 31 I used the closest unsigned int to it ( all 1's) this means that 1 case out of all of them will produce the incorrect result, I figured that's not a big deal.

I was thinking that you could use a `std::vector<bool>` as a very large lookup table on wether to add 1 or subtract 1, seems like overkill to me for an operation that seems to run quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

As @aaronman pointed out, if you are working with integers only the fastest way to do this is to have all powers of 2 in table as there are not that many. By construction, in an unsigned 32 bit integer there are 32 powers of 2 (including the number 1), in a 64 bit integer there are 64 and so on.

But if you want to do it on the fly for a generic case you can easily calculate the surrounding powers of 2 of any number. In c/c++:

```
#include <math.h>

(...)

double bottom, top, number, exponent;

number = 1234;    // Set the value for number

exponent = int(log(number) / log(2.0));  // int(10.2691) = 10
bottom = pow(2, exponent);               // 2^10 = 1024
top = bottom * 2;                        // 2048

// Calculate the difference between number, top and bottom and add or subtract
// 1 accordingly
number = (top - number) <  (number - bottom) ? number + 1 : number - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For nearest (not greatest or equal) - see this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned int val = atoi(argv[1]); 
  unsigned int x = val;
  unsigned int result;
  do {
    result = x;
  } while(x &= x - 1);

  if((result >> 1) & val)
    result <<= 1;

  printf("result=%u\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

if you need greatest or equal - change:

```
if((result >> 1) & val)
```

to

```
if(result != val)
```